# AutoOpen externally defined module

Tags: f#, module

Is there a way to AutoOpen an externally defined module? I'd like it to be available throughout a project without opening it in every file. Something like this would be ideal:

```
[<AutoOpen>]
module MyModule = YourNamespace.YourModule //ERROR: Ignoring attributes on module abbreviation
```

I tried this too, which would (hypothetically) make an externally defined module part of the public interface of a new module.

```
module MyModule = 
  module public YourModule = YourNamespace.YourModule //ERROR: Ignoring accessibility attribute on module abbreviation. Module abbreviations are always private.
```

Comment: That's a good question - it would make sense to allow this. Alternative would be to have some compiler argument to automatically open namespace/module, but I don't think there is one currently.

Answer (score 1):

That's a good question - it would make sense to allow this. Alternative would be to have some compiler argument to automatically open namespace/module, but I don't think there is one currently.

*(There doesn't seem to be a better answer than what I wrote in the comment, so I copied it as an answer)*

Comment: I updated the question with a related attempt. Do you know of a way to partially achieve either of these?